# Color a cell if the text inside it is not the first time it has appeared on the sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

- In cell `A1` I have the text "hello".
- In cell `A2` the text "hello" appears again.
- In cell `A3` I have the text "goodbye".
- In cells `A4:A10` the text "goodbye" appears again.

Is there are a way (with conditional formatting and formulas probably) to find every time the words "hello" and "goodbye" appear *for the second or third or fourth (etc.) time* and color those cells in a certain way? In the example above I would want `A2`, and `A4:A10` to be colored.

Ideally I wouldn't have to add a conditional format rule for "hello" and "goodbye", but could instead have one rule which finds any time a word is repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following rule

```
=countif($A$2:$A2,A2)>1
```

[image: Highlight duplicates except first one]

*(adjust range to your needs)*

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.